# DotNetNuke redirects site root example.com/ to example.com/Default.aspx - why?

Tags: iis-7, dotnetnuke

After moving a DNN 4.3.7 website from a Windows 2003 to a Windows 2008 server (IIS 7), entering the URL automatically results in a redirect to `Default.aspx`. When you create a Google sitemap, the root node is named "Object moved" which is ugly.

There are no HTTP Redirects added to IIS 7. We are using Helicon ISAPI rewrite, but there are no relating settings either.

It probably has to do with IIS 7 because we did not have this problem on IIS 6. On the other hand, other non-DNN sites on the same server do not have that problem, neither do other DNN-sites on other IIS 7 servers.

I am overlooking something obvious. But what?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you are talking about entering http://www.mysite.com and it becomes http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx?

Comment: Do you have friendly urls turned on?

Comment: Do you have a third party url provider installed? Example http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Friendly_Url_Provider_For_DNN

Comment: @Matt, @notandy: we only have Helicon ISAPI Rewrite and Snapsis Pageblaster running, using exactly the same configuration as on the Win2003/IIS 6 system, AND there is no rule that'd do something like this. Are there any "hidden" URL providers that I might be unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, you checked the Documents tab on the site in IIS. The "Enable default content page" might be it.

In Host Settings, there is a Friendly URLs section, which might also be the culprit.

Comment: The Documents tab of IIS 6 has become the Default Document feature in IIS 7. It is enabled by default.
All redirects/friendly URLs are either from Helicon ISAPI Rewrite and Snapsis Pageblaster, no Friendly URLs are set.

Comment: That did it, indirectly. There was a header redirect in an old default.asp to Default.aspx. An by default, default.asp was above Default.aspx in the Default document section (wonder why). Embarrassing, but it took us long to see it.